# Navigator.push has access to previous page - flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

in my app I have implemented various pages that open in different conditions, to open the pages I always used

```
 Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPage())
                  );
```

I always did my tests on iOS simulators but now I tried in android and I discovered that if I use the go back button of the phone the previous page shows up, is there a way to close the page?

Comment: Use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not let user go back to previous screen I would use:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context, routeID, (route) => false);
```

Where routeID is the route you want to push to.